# Writing a denial of proposition?

Tags: logic

How would I write a denial of the following proposition.

Neither $z<s$ nor $z\le t$ is true. (Assume z,t and s are natural numbers)

I think $P=z<s$ is not true

$Q=z\le t$ is not true

And neither can be seen as both so that would and I think.

$\neg (P\wedge Q)$

So then would be $\neg P \vee  \neg Q$

As the denials?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "negation", not "denials". Denial means that I'm not allowing you to do something, negation means the opposite [truth value] of what that was said.

Comment: Hmm I guess negation would seem more correct I  use denial because of the text book question says "denial"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fine, but you might want to translate back:

$\lnot P \lor \lnot Q$ means **not** ($\underbrace{\lnot (z\lt s)}_P)$), or **not** $(\underbrace{\lnot (z\leq t)}_Q)$, in other words, $z \lt s$ or $z \leq t$

Comment: I see so it is the double negative rule in logic